# Syntax issue in Pascal with "pos"

Tags: syntax, pascal

so all i want, is to save the spot in which the dot (.) appears in my string into the variabe: "postemp".
So im writing this code:

```
PosTemp := Pos('.',Dateiname);
```

`Dateiname` is the string that looks as follows: "#1: Bisasam. // 11 kg ".
So, technically, PosTemp should now contempt "12". But when i compile, Lazarus gives me:

> Fatal, Syntax Error: ";" expected, but "(" found.

I dont know why on earth it is not accepting my code...
Any help?

regards

Mo

Here is the full code:

```
FUNCTION LoadGame() : STRING;

VAR Dateiname, Temp : String;
    Textdatei : Text;
    Frage, PosTemp, PosTemp2 : Integer;


BEGIN

  Frage := 99;

  Clrscr;

  Writeln('Welcher Speicherstand soll geladen werden?');
  Writeln;
  Readln(Dateiname);
  Readln(Dateiname);
  Dateiname := Dateiname+'.txt';

  Clrscr;



  Assign(Textdatei,Dateiname);
  Reset(Textdatei);
  WHILE NOT EoF(Textdatei) DO
  BEGIN
        Readln(Textdatei,Dateiname);
        Writeln(Dateiname);
  END;
  Close(Textdatei);

  WHILE (Frage <> 1) AND (Frage <> 0) DO
  BEGIN
        Writeln;
        Writeln('Diesen Spielstand laden?');
        Writeln;
        Writeln('1: Ja');
        Writeln;
        Writeln('0: Nein');
        Writeln;
        Readln(Frage);
  END;

  IF Frage = 0 THEN
  BEGIN
        Clrscr;
        Hauptmenu();
  END;

  IF Frage = 1 THEN
  BEGIN

        Reset(Textdatei);
        Writeln;

        IF NOT EoF(Textdatei) THEN
        BEGIN

              Readln(Textdatei,Dateiname);
              Writeln(Dateiname);

              // NUMMER
              Temp := Copy(Dateiname,2,1);  // Speichert Position als Str
              PosTemp := StrToInt(Temp);    // Position wird als Int gespeichert
              Pos := PosTemp;
              Liste := AddElement(Name, Pos, KG, Liste);  // Pos wird an AddElement übergeben

              // NAME
              PosTemp := Pos(' ',Dateiname);
              PosTemp2:= Pos('.',Dateiname);
              Temp := Copy(Dateiname,PosTemp+1,
              Name := Temp;
              Liste := AddElement(Name, Pos, KG, Liste);



        END;


  END;

  ClrScr;
  Writeln('Laden erfolgreich!');
  Readkey;
  Submenu();
```

Comment: Please give us the full source code. We cannot know what's wrong.

Comment: Error in this line: `Temp := Copy(Dateiname,PosTemp+1,`

Comment: I know, this is, because the line above is producing the error and since i dont know why, i just continued programming. The line is just not completed yet. But why does the part before give me a syntax error?

Comment: Fix that line first. Then compile again.

Comment: Its fixed but it does not compile :( Still says Pos expects a ; and not a ().

Comment: okay i think im onto the problem: i have a variable that is called pos already. so it might confuse the 2 pos es...?

Comment: Yes, likely. In two places there are a reference to pos as a variable. Note for the future that most problems like these are solved by writing a complete compilable minimal self-contained example.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 Pos := PosTemp;
```

looks dodgy. Pos is not declared as variable in the code, and thus defined as (System unit) procedure.

Note that the example code still is not complete and doesn't compile. If you do have a variable Pos, try to prefix the references to the function with System, like

```
  PosTemp := System.Pos(' ',Dateiname);
```